# How can I drag and drop with multiple activities?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-activity

I used the `Service` call to create a Floating Window that floats over all other views/activities. This window has its own `Activity` and is different from Dialog.

Now i want to add a Drag&Drop action to this window, for example if you long click an `ImageView` in the Floating Window, you can Drag and Drop it into another `Activity`(or base Activity). I've been tried to use `OnLongClickListener` to trigger Drag event, and added `OnDragListener` to catch the Drop event. Here's what i have so far :

```
public class MyFloatableActivity extends FloatActivity {
private ImageView mImg;

private MyDragEventListener mDragListen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.float_activity));

    // This imageView is for Drag&Drop test
    mImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drag_img));
    mImg.setOnLongClickListener(new ImageView.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText("dragtext", "dragtext");

            v.startDrag(dragData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
            return false;
        }

    });

    mImg.setOnDragListener(mDragListen);

    switchToFloat(); // Make this activity to float
}
```

MyDragEventListener class is :

```
public class MyDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

private ClipData mDragData;

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    ImageView img;

    if(v instanceof ImageView) {
        img = (ImageView)v;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

    switch(action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            if(event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                Log.d("DDD", "Drag started!!!");
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d("DDD", "Entered!!!");
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d("DDD", "Action drop!!!");
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The reason i implemented `OnDragListener` is to listen `ACTION_DROP` event in base Activity when `ImageView` is dropped. This allows me to determine whether the ImageView was dropped on the destination image, or the layout. Here's my base Activity :

```
public class DragAndDropDemo extends Activity {

private ImageView mImg;

private MyDragEventListener mDragListen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop);

    //findViewById(R.id.drag_layout).setOnDragListener(mDragListen);

    mImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dest_img);

    mImg.setOnDragListener(mDragListen);
}
```

The problem is `OnDragListener` in `DragAndDropDemo` is not being invoked, so i couldn't catch the Drop event in my base Activity. I've seen many examples of Drag and Drop, but never got to the right solution. I'm wondering if throwing a Drag&Drop event to different Activity in Android is possible. If Android could do it, what would it be?

Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. I integrated `OnDragListener` into `MyFloatableActivity`, and send intent to `DragAndDropDemo` activity to receive intents whenever a drop event occurs.

So here's my code.

```
public class MyFloatableActivity extends FloatActivity {
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

    mImg.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                            ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    return true;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("com.test.DragAndDrop");
                    intent.putExtra("Drop", 0);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

    });
...
}
```

and in DragAndDropDemo,

```
public class DragAndDropDemo extends Activity {
...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.test.DragAndDrop");
    registerReceiver(mBR, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mBR);
}

BroadcastReceiver mBR = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int flag = intent.getIntExtra("Drop", 0);
        switch (flag) {
            case 0:
                mText.setText("dropped!");
                mImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_argentina);
                break;
        }
    }

};
}
```